# PHP MySQL dropdown not populating

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
 <?php
 require ('mysql_connect.php');
 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 ?>
 <html>
 <head> <title> Training booking </title> </head >
 <body>
 <p > <b> Student Training Booking Form </b> </p >

 <form action = "training.php " method = "get " >
     <label> Name :
         <input name=" name " placeholder=" Name " type="  "><br />
             Email :
         <input name=" email " placeholder=" example@example.com " 
 type=" "><br />
     </label>
  </form >

  <p > Please Select a Training session </p >
  <select name="top">
  <option value="0">--TOPICS--</option>
  <?php
  $query = ("SELECT topic_name FROM topic");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   ?>
  {
   <option> <?php echo $query ['topic_name']   ?> </option>
   }
   </select>
```

Hi, Im trying to populate a simple dropdown with MySQL and the dropdown is not populating it just stays empty. Can someone please help me out.(I know the code is all over the place.)

**UPDATE**

Code now looks like this and its still not working.

```
<p > Please Select a Training session </p >
<?php
$sql = "SELECT topic_name FROM topic";
$query = mysqli_query($sql);
?>

<select name="topic">
<option value="0">--TOPICS--</option>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?><option><?php echo $row ['topic_name']   ?></option><?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Anyone know whats going wrong?

Comment: That's not how you run queries, more like, you did not run the query.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have tried so many ways and nothing works :( Before it was printing the letter 'W' in the drop down and now its printing the letter 'S'. I really dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing "S" in your dropdown because you are treating your query string as an array and displaying the first letter:

```
echo $query['topic_name']
```

A query must be performed before a result row can be fetched.
Compare [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

```
$query = "SELECT topic_name FROM topic";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   ?><option><?=$row['topic_name']?></option><?php
}
```

Incidentally, I also recommend using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help however I have tried to implement this into my code however now the drop down is empty.

Comment: To troubleshoot: What does your database table look like? What is the value of `$query`? Does [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) return anything? Any PHP errors? Are you running PHP earlier than v5.4.0 with [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) turned off?

Comment: I am quite new to programming but the database has only two tables and the table i am trying to select from here has only two columns, topic_name and topic_id. Query should just be the query to retrieve the information from the database. There are no mysql errors therefore it seems like its connecting fine. I am using the latest version of PHP. Im not sure what "short_open_tag" is. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What I mean is, try to troubleshoot. For example: `var_dump(mysql_error($mysqli));`